# JSON specification

Tags: json

I am C programmer. I want to give JSON message specification to external vendor.
How standard JSON message specification will look ?
There are number of json messages out there in the web.

How basic json message specifications will look without any data ?

Any sample will work.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean like a schema for your messages? https://json-schema.org

Comment: Links [The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) and [Introducing JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) should be enough to sent. `JSON` is so popular you do not need to send a specification of it. Everyone should know what do you mean by it.